# Why are Typescript annotations not working when using @rollup/plugin-node-resolve?

Tags: angular, typescript, rollup

I have a simple Angular project and I am using rollup to create my artifacts. My rollup looks like this...

```
// rollup.config.mjs

import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript"
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonJS from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

export default {
    input: "index.mjs",
    output: [
        {
            file: getName("esm", "mjs"),
            format: "esm"
        },
        {
            file: getName("umd", "js"),
            format: "umd",
            name: "my-app"
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        commonJS({
            include: 'node_modules/**'
        }),
        resolve(),
    ]
};

// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "module": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

Then I have a simple wrapper...

```
// index.mjs
import {Application} from "./Application.ts"

export {Application}
```

And then My Angular app

```
//Application.ts
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";

@NgModule()
export class Application{}

// TestComponent.ts
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "test-component",
    template: `
      <h1>This is the test component</h1>
    `
})
class TestComponent {

}
```

But when I run `rollup -c rollup.config.mjs` I get....

```
1: import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
2:
3: @NgModule(
   ^
4:
5: )
Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
    at error (...\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:213:30)
```

How do I get rollup to recognize this? If I remove the `plugin-node-resolve` everything seems to work (except resolving dependencies)

How should I handle this?

**Update**

Here is the final file after compile without resolve...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

/*! *****************************************************************************
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH
REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY
AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT,
INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM
LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR
OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR
PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
***************************************************************************** */

function __decorate(decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
}

let Application = class Application {
    hellowWorld() {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
};
Application = __decorate([
    NgModule()
], Application);

export { Application };
```

But again this does not include the dependencies and I want a UMD bundle with all deps already included.

Comment: `// index.mjs import {Application} from "./Application.ts"` is very wrong. In a TypeScript file, having a explicit `.ts` extension in an import is an error. But in an `.mjs` file it is going to cause these sorts of problems. Rollup will not use the TypeScript plugin to compile the `.mjs` file and, i's clearly not passing the dependency, `./application.ts` to the plugin.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Not sure I follow again all of this compiles fine until I try to use the resolve function. Since index.mjs is an mjs it can have (and in fact in newer spec is required) to have an extension. This is so in addition to signifying module JS and Typescript it can distinguish jsx vs js or tsx vs ts or even cjs vs mjs. But I digress, are you saying this is not possible? Because I have a feeling I can sub in babel but trying to prevent a bunch of config.

Comment: That is what I am saying. Specifying an explicit `.ts` extension **anywhere** in your _source_ code is a bug. If you used TypeScript's `"allowJs": true` it would probably transpile the file, but TypeScript doesn't support compilin `.mjs` files so its out of the entire loop by the time the resolution happens.

Comment: I could be wrong, it could be that Rollup is smart and will see that the extension is `.ts` and pass it to the TS plugin for transpilation, SystemJS can be configured to do that quite easily, but it seems clear from the error that this is not what Rollup is doing.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I think I see what you mean, but since it is pretranspile rollup seems to be smart enough to know what to do with it because the ESM comes out looking right. I suppose the resolve plugin could also be doing that then throwing an error so maybe I can tell it not to follow that dependency somehow?

Comment: That error looks like it is coming through Babel. That means the decorators in the source aren't transpiled. Even with `"target": "esnext"` decorators will be transpiled by TS.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried converting the file to a .ts file instead of a .mjs file but I get the same thing

Comment: You tried `// index.ts import {Application} from "./Application";`? If that isn't being compiled that's very odd.